# Stop playing sound called via SoundEffect.FromStream

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

I have some Windows Phone 7 code that starts playing a sound using SoundEffect.FromStream. I am using this instead of a normal media object as I need multiple audio clips to be on the one page.

However, based on certain external events I want to stop a particular sound playing. As sounds played via Open Stream are "play and forget" I cannot work out how to reference this playing sound and stop it.

```
    public void PlaySoundCircus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (audioPlaying == false)
        {
            using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("circus.wav"))
            {
                var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
                FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
                effect.Play();
            }
            audioPlaying = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a [SoundEffectInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance_members.aspx) which will store a reference to your `SoundEffect`. The `SoundEffectInstance` has a `Stop` method which can be called.

```
SoundEffectInstance seiCircus;

using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("circus.wav"))
{
    var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
    //create the instance
    seiCircus = effect.CreateInstance();

    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    //play sound via the instance
    seiCircus.Play();
}

//some event called to stop sound
seiCircus.Stop();
```