# how to play a sound in wp7 when user clicks a icon

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio

I've many 'words' in my project. There is a listen icon next to each words. I want to know how i can play a sound when user clicks on the icon. All my sound clippings are only of 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Use the XNA SoundEffect class.

You find a code sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017517/windows-phone-7-stop-playing-sound-called-via-soundeffect-fromstream), where a similar question has already been asked.