# Speaker not turned off after sound effect has been played on windows phone

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, xna, soundeffect

we play a sound effect in our windows phone notification. the sound plays normally but after that, the speaker seems to be still turned on and we can hear a noice.
Here the code:

```
var soundEffect = SoundEffect.FromStream(_soundStream);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
soundEffect.Play();
```

We also tried to keep an instance of `SoundEffect` or even tried it using a `SoundEffectInstance`, but the result ist the same.

We are testing on Nokia Lumia 520, but the noice problem occures on other device models as well.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017517/stop-playing-sound-called-via-soundeffect-fromstream

Comment: the sound is actually stopped, but there is just a noice after the sound has played. i can only hear it when i put the phone on my ear, it stops if the app is closed or goes to sleep